# Is there a reason it's not possible to use tablet keyboard cases across brands?

Tags: keyboard, tablet, case

Case:

I've got a tablet from brand ***XyZ***. I want to use a physical tablet keyboard case for it. This is a device which combines a tablet case with a built-in physical keyboard. The only tablet keyboard case which meets my desired specs is from another brand, ***aBc***. It basically turns the tablet into a laptop, literally, so no need for a table or flat surface. It has a track/touchpad and a backlit. For reasons only known to them, XyZ doesn't make that type of tablet keyboard case, for *their ówn* tablets.

They both use **blue-tooth** in these devices. **Now, would it be impossible to use the ABC keyboard with the XYZ tablet?** NOT talking about the physical aspects like camera placement etc. Just about whether the tablet would (easily) accept input from the keyboard because they both use Blue-Tooth, which is universal ...

Question:
**Is there a *„software-matic”*  issue or any other, which would prevent this? To use them together?**

Perhaps the answers could range from [a] *„will never ever work”* to [b] *„will work 100% of the time”* and also, going via [c] *„will only work after certain conditions are met, condition 1 is... condition 2 is.... condition 3 is.... ”*

Structuring your answers like that helps me with the Asperger. Thanks for that.

PS *Not written to promote either brand in any way, nor asking for recommendations.*

EDIT: To make this all a little less vague, I can name the brands, if it won't result in downvotes because it'd be seen as promotion or whatever.

Comment: there is no hyphen in Bluetooth ... it is a person's  name

Comment: Is that the reason for your downvote? A hyphen?

Comment: You can generally use a Bluetooth keyboard from one manufacturer with another manufacturers device.

Comment: Do you mean to ask: can I use any blue-tooth keyboard with a tablet?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen that is asking it from the other angle, yes, but I'm interested **if** it can be done and if not, why not. But sure, you can see the way you put it as the *long-story-short* version, why not. I merely wanted to be thorough, given the nature of this site.

Comment: AFAIK you should be able to use any Bleutooth keyboard, yes. Bluetooth is a standard, a protocol that is brand independent.

Comment: @SaraPhina what downvote are you asking about? ... I did not downvote your post

Comment: The maker of the tablet keyboard case will state whether or not their case supports a given table brand and model. WHY a given case does or does not support a given model is a complex question we cannot answer.

Comment: Your question is not bad, per se, but it is not about computer hardware and software within the limits defined in our Help section. You can review this yourself to confirm it.

Comment: @music2myear I'm sorry to do that. I can not find the help section you seem to be referring to, would you mind telling me at least one reason why its `outside the limits` ??

Comment: This site is about personal computers, not mobile devices. If you have a tablet that runs a common desktop OS it may be on topic. This site isn't about why a given brand doesn't make a specific sort of accessory. This site isn't about recommending hardware. The Help links are found in the upper right corner of this site, on both desktop and mobile layouts.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. But please note i didn't mention any brand name, other than `Bluetooth` which is more a standard than a brand, or rather, a brand that became a standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is more or less like your {C} option:

Yes, you can use a keyboard from one brand with another branded tablet, provided the following conditions are met:

1. they both use Android. So, you can use a Samsung tablet with a Windows keyboard. (assuming that Windows KB uses Android)
2. if you use a Samsung keyboard with an iPad tablet according to this article: https://getnotifyr.com/connecting-your-samsung-keyboard-to-an-ipad-a-step-by-step-guide/

I haven't found the reverse of 2 to be true, the reason might be that iPad/Apple uses a different BT protocol that Samsung

And Apple uses a proprietary connector called the Smart Connector, Samsung Android tablets, on the other hand, use micro-USB or USB-C connector for keyboard connectivity.

Also, even if they both use BT  iPad is probably not compatible with Android devices because they use other Bluetooth protocols

If they do work together then my **life-hack** would be to get a iPad KB which is slightly bigger than your tablet (for example a 25,9 cm KB with a 25,65 tablet) and then stick it to the keyboard case with Velcro)

The proof of the pudding is in the eating...

Comment: What is a 'keyboard *using* Android', please?

Comment: "Apple uses a proprietary connector " - but that's not what the question is about at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to use any Bleutooth keyboard.

Just as an example, Apple states:

> Using a Bluetooth connection, you can use *third-party devices* (emphasis by me) such as
> wireless keyboards, headphones, speakers, car kits, game controllers,
> and more with iPad.

https://support.apple.com/en-gu/guide/ipad/ipad997da4cf/ipados